# Locate rows in one dataframe based on criteria from another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have created two Dataframes from  a main dataframe, e.g. df1 and df2.

Each dataframe has the same no of columns, but no of rows in df2 will be less than in df1. The dataframe will have columns waferlot,x,y,w.

How can search for waferlot,x,y,w from df2 in df1.

Comment: you're looking for `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[waferlot,x,y,w])`

Comment: Can you give an example of input data and expected output?

Comment: Ashish Acharya, need to try out. looks to me a good solution.

Comment: Ashish  I tried the solution, but gives me KeyError: 'K123456-01'.

Answer (score 0):

While there can be multiple ways to achieve this, one of which has been mentioned in the comments, but I usually do it using [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

Given two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['C1'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
df1['C2'] = ['b', 'c', 'x', 'w', 'h', 'j']
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 ['C1'] = ['x', 'a', 'c', 'f']
df2 ['C2'] = ['w', 'h', 'd', 'j']
```

The dataframes look like:

```
In [144]: df1
Out[144]:
  C1 C2
0  a  b
1  b  c
2  c  x
3  d  w
4  e  h
5  f  j

In [145]: df2
Out[145]:
  C1 C2
0  x  w
1  a  h
2  c  d
3  f  j
```

Now, I can use isin to search for whatever I want across all columns of the dataframe.

```
x = (df1[df1.C1.isin(df2.C1) & df1.C2.isin(df2.C2)])
```

Output:

```
  C1 C2
5  f  j
```

If you want to search on one column only then, you can remove one of the conditions before or after the `&`:

```
x = (df1[df1.C1.isin(df2.C1)])
```

Output:

```
  C1 C2
0  a  b
2  c  x
5  f  j
```

Comment: Thank you! trollster I will try out and feedback

Comment: I tried your method, but it seems I am getting extra rows from the larger dataframe. Sorry I am unable to share the data for some security reason

Comment: You can create some smaller dataset with fake data and describe your problem. What do you mean by you are getting extra rows?